# Matrix with the matrix elements

Tags: matlab

I want to create a matrix in large dimensions that the components themselves are a matrix.
Like the following example

[image]

each of the `W`, `V`, `U` is `18*18` matrix and the other components are zero. What is the easiest way to create such a matrix in `MATLAB`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want a matrix that contains `n x n` blocks so its dimensions will be `(18 * n) x (18 * n)`:

```
n=10;
z=ones(n,1);
result = kron(spdiags(z,-1,n,n),V)+kron(spdiags(z,0,n,n),U)+kron(spdiags(z,1,n,n),W);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but the `U`, `W` and `V` matrices are not just at the top and bottom of the matrix, they are diagonally repeated over the matrix.

Comment: @rahnema 1. Thank you very much. Your answer helps me a lot.